# Is there a way to use a forum's user management for rest of site?

Tags: php, forum, credentials, mybb

I just set up a MyBB forum.  I have a site that I want to provide other features to such as saving text.  But to do so I need user credentials.  So I am wondering if I can leverage the forum's user management system to see if a user is logged in and what group he is in.

My domain structure is like this:  http://www.mainsite.com/forum

I am using PHP.  I have no problem querying the forum's database but do I get logged in status from a session value?  What should I include in my PHP files?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a [bridge](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=mybb%20bridge&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=565fde9959e2c890&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.eWU&biw=1440&bih=810)

Comment: You should at least specify the type of forum you are using...

Comment: Steve, you should at least read the first sentence.

Comment: @Mike, I'd never heard of such a bridge.  That is exactly what I'm looking for!  If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as THE answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an authentication bridge aka a way to use one system's authentication api in another.